# Automatically go to next row when certain number of characters is entered

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I am creating an Excel sheet where there is a comments section that has a column width of 58 characters.

Is it possible for someone entering comments to have it automatically go to the next row once they enter 55 characters in the row above? I don't want to use wrap text and need to maintain the rows in this section.

Answer (score 0):

You could use VBA and the `Worksheet_Change` event

Here a starting point

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim str As String
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 3 Then  ' Only Column C
            If Not Target.HasFormula Then
                If Len(Target) > 55 Then
                    str = CStr(Target)
                    Target = Left$(str, 55)
                    Target.Offset(1, 0) = Mid$(str, 56)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You will need to modify to suit your exact needs